# calculate number of ways to achive opposite Vertex

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Hi I have a problem with following task:
We have regular octagon. We start from one vertex want to move to the opossite one. We can only move to an vertex thats next to us( we may go right or left for each) now my task is to calculate the ways to get from starting vertex to opposite one doing exactly $n$ moves and opposite vertex is achived only at the end. 
Will be glad for hint and or sugestions as I am stuck with this one for a long time. 
[image]

Comment: What do moves "upward, backward" mean? Are any moves to adjacent vertices allowed?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't strict enough. I edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have figured it out. If anyone is interested, here is a sketch of solution. 
Lets say our starting point is called A next(going counter clockwise) is called B and so on we call all vertexes with alphabet letters. Our end point will be then called E.
Let $a_n$ by a number of ways to get from $A$ to $A$ making $n$ moves. $b_n$ be a nuber of ways to go to $B$ from $A$ making $n$ moves and so on. We are interested in $e_n$ as it is a number of ways to get to $E$ from $A$. We form a system of equations:
$$a_n=b_{n-1}+h_{n-1}=2b_{n-1}$$
$$b_n=a_{n-1}+c_{n-1}$$
$$c_n=b_{n-1}+d_{n-1}$$
$$d_n=c_{n-1}$$
$$e_n=d_{n-1}+f_{n-1}=2d_{n-1}$$
Now we calcualte $e_{n+1}=2d_n=...=$ and just plug our system of equation here to get expresion with $e_{n-i}$ only. We get: $e_{n+1}=2\cdot e_{n-1}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot e_{n-3}$

Comment: This is still not in "closed form", meaning a single nonrecursive formula in terms of $n.$ Any luck on getting that?

Comment: If $e_4$ is how many ways to do it in exactly $4$ moves, that should come out $1$ or $2,$ depending on whether going clockwise is counted the same or different from counterclockwise. Your formula above, to get this case, would need $n=3$ and give $2e_1-(1/2)e_{-1}.$ I suppose one counts any encounter of negative subscripts as zero, however then $e_1$ would be how many ways to do it in one move which is zero since it cannot be done in one move (all the way from one vertex to its opposite takes at least four moves). I must be missing something about your definitions.

Comment: We differ clockwise and counterclockwise.So $e_4=2$ I have checked it once again and it seems I made some mistakes when solving equations, I will correct it later. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I did $e_6$ using a different recursion and got $6$ ways total, which tallies with just finding all the ways. If interested I could put the details in an "answer" [too long for a comment].

Comment: After adjustments, I have came up with :$e_{n+1}=3e_{n-1}-e_{n-3}$ And we use it for $n\ge4$. So $e_6=3\cdot e_{4}-e_{2}=3\cdot 2=6$. Our results match, so I guess it should be fine now.

Comment: It may not match for higher $n.$ It would be more convincing if it matched results found by explicit listing of paths for say $n=8,10,12,14.$ [I would be surprised if the simple recurrence of your last comment always works, buy maybe it does.]